# Yii2 Remove container div specific to every record from listview

Tags: html, listview, yii2

I want remove   from  listview
this tag is auto generate
for example

```
echo ListView::widget(
    [
        'summary' => false,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            $itemContent = $this->render(
                '_post', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'index' => $index,
                    'key' => $key
                ]
            );

            // /* Display an Advertisement after the first list item */
            // if ($index == 0) {
            //     $adContent = $this->render('_ad');
            //     $itemContent .= $adContent;
            // }

            return $itemContent;

            /* Or if you just want to display the list item only: */
            // return $this->render('_list_item',['model' => $model]);
        }

    ]
);
```

and html generate is :

```
<div class="item" data-key="361"><!-- <div class="post"> -->


<div class='col-md-12' style="border:2px solid red" >
```

I want remove

```
<div class="item" data-key="361">
```

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well not sure what effect it would create as it is the actual id of the record/row that is being displayed, but you can do that by using the [`itemOptions`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview#$itemOptions-detail) options which takes an array and you can pass `"tag"=>null` see below.

```
echo ListView::widget(
    [
        'summary' => false,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemOptions' => ['tag' => null],
        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            $itemContent = $this->render(
                '_post', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'index' => $index,
                    'key' => $key
                ]
            );
            return $itemContent;
        }

    ]
);
```